# Receiving Multiple Msg queue from VectorCanCase

Tags: embedded, can-bus

when sending a specific CAN message via chanel 0x74D the lenght is specified in l=8 and the response must contain several Ca, msg, unfortunatly i receive only the first one, please note also that all the received msg are in chanel 0x76D .
im using C# code, here attach a question that i have answered but with no response

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933398/how-can-i-specify-data-lenght-received-by-cancasexl-from-vector

any idea on how to do that ?